# Origin for different styles in splitting up El Adon and Lecha Dodi

Tags: minhag, tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader, nusach-ashkenaz, nusach-sefard

In most Nusach Ashkenaz shuls that I have attended, the congregation and chazzan sing *Lecha Dodi* and *Kel Adon* together.

In most Hassidic minyanim (they are Nusach Sefard. I say "Hassidic" since the majority of Nusach Seafrd shuls I have attended are Hassidic shtieblach) they do not sing together, but, rather, the chazzan sings a verse, then the congregation repeats it (a.k.a. sung responsively, which is specifically **not** the topic of [To sing or not to sing - Piyutim on Shabbath](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12771/to-sing-or-not-to-sing-piyutim-on-shabbath?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

How did these different minhagim originate?

Also, is there a halachically preferred method?

(I think that this is a general rule for all cong. "songs" but these are the only two that I can think of where I see differences.)

Comment: Well, what you call the "Hassidic" method is definitely older. If that makes it preferred or not isn't so clear.

Comment: I think this question is asking the difference between congregations that sing it stanza by stanza vs. those that sing it together.

Comment: that sounds intriguing. I haven't seen those sung stanza by stanza yet. you have a link to a recording of them being sung this way? Would also be interested to hear what the tune would be like sung this way

Comment: Italians split the verses of Lekha dodi: the first sentence is sung by the chazan, the second is by the congregation