# History of How to Recite Kel Adon

Tags: minhag, history, song-poetry

In the Shabbos *shacharis* *birkos kerias shema*, there is a poem referred to as Kel Adon that we say.

In some congregations, the custom is to say the stanzas responsively, with the *chazzan* saying each stanza and then the congregation repeating it. In other congregations, the custom is that everyone says the entire poem straight through together.

[This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60360/4794) question (which is in turn currently a duplicate of [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12771/4794) question) asks why there is a discrepancy in custom, and if either method is preferred.

I am (under the assumption that one custom was the original way and the other evolved later) curious when whichever custom is later started. All sourced answers are welcome.

Comment: I've always wondered if Tur 281 was referring this

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60360/759

Comment: @רבותמחשבות If you think it needs to be closed, that q is a dupe of yet a third q which does have an answer. But I happen to think that at least one point of my question, namely when the later custom started, is not included there.

Comment: @Yez **exactly the problem**, the third question doesn't answer the detail of the second question which you asked a duplicate of.  In other words: It's not a duplicate of the third question, it's a duplicate of the one DoubleAA found only.  That one is the one that we cannot flag as a dupe.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Sorry, I think you misunderstood me. _Neither_ of those two questions asks _when_ this change, whichever direction it happened, happened. It isn't a dupe of either question, in my opinion.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות As an aside, if you think that my question is a dupe of one of those questions but not another, then you should probably vote to reopen the one that is closed as a dupe, as you seem to feel there is an element of that question which is not covered in the other question.

Comment: @Yez Re: Comment 1: not sure what I think of that logic - would "*how* did this difference originate" include a "*when*"?  Maybe, maybe not.  At the very least, I would note the question.  Good point, though.  Perhaps add a "based on this question, I have a follow-up".  Re: Comment 2: I think that there is an element that is new, and I will go now and vote to reopen.  But credit to you for thinking of this question, it's a good one!  And thanks for the guidance, I'm still getting used to all of these rules...

Comment: @רבותמחשבות As an עצה טובה, you may want to include a comment there explaining why you are voting to reopen, so people who see it in the review queue know what is going on.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Again, there being one new aspect doesn't make the whole post not a duplicate. Remove the duplicate parts (or summarize the results therein as relevant background), and the question can be reopened.

Comment: @Yez can we do what DoubleAA is suggesting, namely edit out any resemblance to older questions?

Comment: @DoubleAA I believe I've fixed the problem. Motion to reopen,